# Migration from AccountStore to SecureStorage not working on Android devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to migrate app settings from an old Xamarin app using AccountStore to a new Xamarin Forms app using SecureStorage. I've found a number of articles on StackOverflow and other sites showing how to do this, but the methods suggested for retrieving the old values from AccountStore are not working for me.

In my old Android project, I have this code. The account variable has the correct values in the emulators I've tested with. I'm using Xamarin.Auth.Android v1.2.3.1 if that matters.

```
var account = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context).FindAccountsForService("x.y.z").FirstOrDefault();
```

In my Xamarin Forms project I have the following code which works on an iOS device and Android 6.0, 8.0, and 10.0 emulators but not on Android 6.0 or 8.0 devices, the only ones I have access to right now.

```
var account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService("x.y.z")?.FirstOrDefault();
```

I've also tried this in the OnCreate of the MainActivity of my Android project of my new Xamarin Forms app.

```
var accounts = AccountStore.Create(this).FindAccountsForService("x.y.z");
var accounts = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context).FindAccountsForService("x.y.z");
```

If I download my old Xamarin app to my device from the Google Play store, enter my settings, and then replace it with the new Xamarin Forms app deployed from Visual Studio, I don't get any settings. However, if I deploy my old Xamarin app to my device from Visual Studio, enter my settings, and then replace it with the new Xamarin Forms app deployed from Visual Studio, I do get my settings. Is it safe to assume that everything will work correctly once I have the new app on the Google Play store?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the official document about the [Migrating from AccountStore to Xamarin.Essentials SecureStorage](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage) on the github wiki?

You can try to use the `var accountStoreAccounts = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(""x.y.z"");` to check if you can get the correct value or not.

And then use the [Migration / Helper Class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage#migration--helper-class) to migrate the saved account to the SecureStorage. After that, you can [retrieve stored accounts](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage#retrieve-stored-accounts).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: I saw the edited part in your question and the cause should be the new Xamarin Forms app deployed from Visual Studio won't be recognized as the same app downloaded from the google. And it's safe to assume that everything will work correctly once you have the new app on the Google Play store. @t_m27